# What is the preg_match concept at use here?

Tags: php, preg-match

The following is in a legacy php app, could someone please explain what is happening here, or what the general terminology is behind the line so I can research it. Mostly I am confused concerning `? $foo : !$foo`

```
preg_match("/^test_item_([0-9]*)/", $foo, $item) ? $foo : !$foo
```

Comment: If `$foo` string matches pattern - return this string. Else return `!$foo`

Comment: its same as a `if` and `else` to return the result

Comment: @Paul Crovella - Thanks very much for that, it will help a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$foo` matches the pattern it is returned as is. Otherwise it is negated, because of the `!`.

This means a few different things, depending on the actual content of `$foo`.

These are possible:

`$foo` is "falsy", eg. `null`, `false`, `''` it returns `true`. In any other case it returns `false`.

Example:

```
$foo = 'test_item_1'; // leads to 'test_item_1'
$foo = 'test_item';   // leads to false
$foo = '';            // leads to true
```

This is quite horrible behaviour, you should make the intent much clearer.

Comment: Excellent, clear and helpful, thanks very much. Also knowing it's not the best (clearest) code is most insightful.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` precedes the *true* condition's output, the `:` precedes the *false* condition's output.

Lots of people get muddled up when trying to process & display boolean values.  Here is a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc565273c184767be29e642d9d5e656bf76a1113) using `echo` and `var_export()` to display the shorthand conditional's outputs:

```
$foo='test_item_1';
var_export(preg_match("/^test_item_([0-9]*)/", $foo, $item)?$foo:!$foo);
echo "\n";
echo preg_match("/^test_item_([0-9]*)/", $foo, $item)?$foo:!$foo;

echo "\n\n---\n\n";

$foo='failing string';
var_export(preg_match("/^test_item_([0-9]*)/", $foo, $item)?$foo:!$foo);
echo "\n";
echo preg_match("/^test_item_([0-9]*)/", $foo, $item)?$foo:!$foo;


echo "\n\n---\n\n";

$foo='';
var_export(preg_match("/^test_item_([0-9]*)/", $foo, $item)?$foo:!$foo);
echo "\n";
echo preg_match("/^test_item_([0-9]*)/", $foo, $item)?$foo:!$foo;
```

Output:

```
'test_item_1'
test_item_1     // the string as expected

---

false
                // print empty string

---

true
1               // converts true to 1
```

As you can see, using `echo` will likely lead to confusion.  `var_export()` tells a very accurate tale of the output.